# iptables: unknown option "--dport"

Tags: ssh, iptables, tcp

When I try to run `iptables -A control_in -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` I get the error message `iptables v1.4.20: unknown option "--dport"`. Everything I've found on the internet and serverfault relating to this message was due to people not specifying a protocol. However I am doing that (`-p tcp`). I've also tried running it with multiple `--verbose` options but I don't get any more info.

**Edit:** Michael Hampton's answer led me to the correct answer. It was a broken iptables install that was missing some libraries from /usr/lib/xtables. The `--match` argument is redundant if iptables is given the `-p` argument, except that it only complains about the missing libraries if given `--match`.

Comment: Shum, please consider writing your solution up as an answer an accepting it; it will stop this question floating around forever, like a querulous albatross!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--dport` is part of the `tcp` **match**, which is `-m` or `--match`.

This would work:

```
iptables -A control_in -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: In my case, this gives me the following error: `iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): Couldn't load match `tcp':No such file or directory`

Comment: The above syntax works for me with `iptables v1.8.4 (legacy)` on Ubu 20.04. The iptables TCP module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables/libxt_tcp.so` is owned by the iptables package. Maybe you're missing some files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing sudo. Try adding `sudo` at the start of the command.